# Extra condition for characterization of prime ideals in quadratic number fields based on quadratic residues

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Exercise I.3.3 of Jürgen Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory* ([link](http://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Eila/Neukirch_Algebraic_number_theory.pdf) to an English version, the exercise is on page 23 of the book, page 36 of the pdf) says

> Let $d$ be squarefree and $p$ a prime number not dividing $2d$. Let $\mathcal O$ be the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$. Show that $(p)=p\mathcal O$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal O$ if and only if the congruence $x^2\equiv d\bmod p$ has no solution.

You can find my elementary attempt below, but the purpose of this question is not primarily a solution to the exercise. I am curious about the requirement that $p$ should not divide $2d$. Now, I see that $p\neq 2$ might be necessary, since there are elements in $\mathcal O$ with a $2$ in the denominator, and for this reason I use $p\neq2$ at multiple steps of my proof.

However, I do not see a problem if $p\neq 2, p\mid d$. In that case, $0^2\equiv d\bmod p$ is always a solution, and $\sqrt d\cdot\sqrt d=d\in(p)$, but $\sqrt d\notin (p)$, so that $(p)$ is not a prime ideal, which is perfectly in line with the statement of the exercise.

Am I missing something or is my argument correct and the requirement $p\nmid d$ is unnecessary? If the latter is the case, why did Neukirch include it in the exercise? Is there maybe a short proof that does not work in this case?

---

For the sake of completion, here is my proof:

If $x^2\equiv d\bmod p$ is a solution to the congruence, then $$x^2-d\equiv 0\bmod p\Longrightarrow (x-\sqrt d)(x+\sqrt d)=x^2-d\in(p),$$ but $x\pm\sqrt d\notin(p)$: For if that were the case, then $$\frac{x\pm\sqrt d}{p}\in\mathcal O,$$ which is impossible considering $p\neq2$ and ${\mathcal O}=\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$ or $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt d}2]$. Hence $(p)$ is not a prime ideal.

Conversely, assume now that $x^2\equiv d\bmod p$ has no solution and let $\alpha,\beta\in\scriptsize\mathcal O$ such that $\alpha\beta\in(p)$. It follows that $$p^2=N(p)\mid N(\alpha\beta)=N(\alpha)N(\beta).$$ Then $p$ divides $N(\alpha)$ or $N(\beta)$, without loss we can assume $p|N(\alpha)$. Put $\alpha=\frac{a+b\sqrt d}{2},a,b\in\mathbb Z,a\equiv b\bmod 2$. (If $d\not\equiv 1\bmod 4$, we additionally have to require that $a$ and $b$ are even.) Then $p$ divides $4N(\alpha)=a^2-b^2d$. If we had $b\not\equiv 0\bmod p$, then $b$ would be invertible $\bmod p$ and $(ab^{-1})^2\equiv d\bmod p$, contradicting the assumption. Thus $p|b$ and then also $p|a$. Since $p\neq2$, we still have $\frac ap\equiv\frac bp\bmod2$, so that $\frac\alpha p\in\scriptsize\mathcal O$, i.e. $\alpha\in(p)$. Therefore, $(p)$ is a prime ideal. $\square$

Comment: I am asking why the exercise requires $p\nmid d$, which seems unnecessary to me. And I am aware  that $2$ is not a unit, I never said it is.

Comment: Sorry,  misinterpeted the thrust of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ does not divide $2d$, then it is unramified in the extension. The case of $p=2$ in quadratic extensions is anomalous.

For $p$ unramified in a quadratic extension $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ with square-free $d$ of $\mathbb Q$, since the ring of integers is *locally*-at-$p$ obtained as $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$. Then (I think Dedekind knew this) the splitting of $p$ in the extension is described by the splitting (or not) of $x^2-d$ over $\mathbb F_p$.

So, the $p$ not dividing $2d$ hypothesis is just to avoid $2$ and to avoid ramified primes.

EDIT: ah, yes, to respond more precisely to the actual question, as @ThomasAndrews comments, the assertion that $p\not=2$ stays prime if and only if $x^2-d$ has no solution mod $p$ is correct *also* for $p|d$. It's just that "$p$ ramified" is has some technical differences from "$p$ split"... and, since only finitely-many primes ramify in a given finite extension, sometimes it's easier to exclude ramified primes (even if something analogous is true for them).

Comment: That motivates why we would care only about $p\not\mid d,$ but the theorem, as stated, is still true for $p\neq 2,$ $p\mid d,$ right?